# Xpath with wildcards returning partial node name

Tags: java, xpath

I am new to Xpath and am trying to parse a UML model saved in XML format.
I have some nodes in the form :-

```
<ModelProfile:create xmi:id='_16_0_1_187c046a_1307545286478_527165_409' base_Element='_16_0_1_187c046a_1307545286478_986851_398'/>

<ModelProfile:get xmi:id='_16_0_1_187c046a_1307545286478_698482_412' base_Element='_16_0_1_187c046a_1307545286478_639036_401'/>
```

I have the `base_Element` value and know that the nodes begin with `ModelProfile:` , but I need to get what the value after the `ModelProfile:` string is - i.e. the word `"get"` or `"create"` in the above 2 examples.

How can I do this in Xpath (in Java)?

Thanks

Sarah

Comment: I suggest you read up on XML namespaces http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have [registered the `ModelProfile` namespace URI](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/xpath/XPath.html#addNamespace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), you can use:

```
"//ModelProfile:*[@base_Element='" + yourBaseElementValue + "']"
```

to get all nodes with that particular `base_Element` attribute value.

From there on you can use the `nodeName` property of the returned nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to identify the elements by where they appear in the document e.g. get all elements that are children of the "umlModel" element. After that it is simple to pull out the local name (the "get" or "create" bit).

The "ModelProfile" part is the namespace prefix which will be bound to a URI. You will need to understand how namespaces work before you will get XPath to work as you expect. The w3c schools intro seems reasonable: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp